# Embed doesnt show up when clicking a link to go to the page with the embedded content

Tags: javascript, html

I'm experiencing one of the strangest web bugs I've seen right now and its kind of hard to explain but I'll try my best to.

I'm hosting a small [flash games website](https://mmgamez.github.io/index.html) and I have run into a bug with the way that I'm embedding games. Because I really don't feel like writing an HTML file for each game to be embedded on, I created a webpage that when you provide a "URL variable" with the file name of the game, it will create an embed element with the source being the filename. This works, but only when I directly type in "https://mmgamez.github.io/play.html?game.swf". If I click on the link that I put on the "Games" page for a game, it won't pop up (at least for me on ChromeOS).

TLDR/Simplified version:

If I type in `https://mmgamez.github.io/play.html?RiddleSchool1.swf` in my URL bar the game Riddle School 1 will show up and be playable.
If I go to the 'Games' tab on my website and click on the link "Riddle School 1" the game will not show up at all.

Heres how I embed my games using a "url variable":

```js
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
var game = getUrlVars()["game"];

function embedFile(){
var el = document.getElementById("gamePlace");
var emb = document.createElement("embed");
    emb.setAttribute("width", "800");
    emb.setAttribute("height", "600");
    emb.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "true");
    emb.setAttribute('src', "games/"+game.toString());
    emb.setAttribute('type', 'application/x-shockwave-flash')
    el.appendChild(emb);
}
```

Why in the world does this happen and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: On you website game is undefined. Vars returns nothing but an empty object.

Comment: Why are you calling it like this `setTimeout(function(){embedFile()}, 500)`?

Comment: @Train that was me attempting to fix the problem but it didn't do much. I originally used `onload` on the body tag

Comment: You can start by fixing `getUrlVars()` Currently it returns nothing but an empty object, and your `replace` function doesn't replace anything. What are you trying to do there? Can you show us a reproducible example online of just that function? It would be a good start.

Comment: Im gonna be honest I got my url variable function by googling "get url variable javascript" so I'll try writing my own function

Comment: Did his solution work by adding to the query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your getUrlVars() function is working correctly. However, with query string values, you are looking for key/value pairs (e.g. key1=value1&key2=value2).

Looking at this line

```
var game = getUrlVars()["game"];
```

I think you just need to change your links to add "game" as the key:

```
<a href="https://mmgamez.github.io/play.html?game=RiddleSchool1.swf">RiddleSchool1</a>
```